# edit textbox value in magento

Tags: magento-1

I am new in magento extension devlopment.

I have to change my textbox value when i am click on button, in magento. Following are some important part of my code. when this same I try in simple PHP it works so why not in magento?

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2(){
            var street = document.getElementById('street_1').value;
            var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
            var state=document.getElementById('region').value;       
            var zip=document.getElementById('zip').value;       
            var newcity=document.getElementById('newcity').value;
            document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=newcity;
            return confirm(city);              
            return true;
    }
   </script>
```

This is button code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my phtml code:

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" id="newcity">
<input type="submit" name="truemagentosubmit" value="This will real submit the form" onclick='changeText2()'/>
```

When I am click on submit button it dosent change the value of textbox whose id is city.

please give me some suggestion on this code. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Why do you want to change that value right at the form submission? If your button is only supposed to change the input value then use a regular button instead of a submit. I don't understand why you would want to change this value and then submit the form immediately after, but it seems like you have the two fields in the form anyways, so maybe you should handle this server-side (without javascript)? That would be inside a controller action, i.e. ``$postData['city'] = $postData['newcity']; $model->setData($postData);``

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are asking but if you want to set the value of the field id="city" then you should use the following.

```
document.getElementById('city').value = newcity;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like from template/customer/address/edit.phtml.

It's best to replace your element input[]type=submit] having name="truemagentosubmit" with an anchor/a html tag. But will not be useful anymore. Remove the tag with name truemagentosubmit.
It looks like you need to execute that function on form submit:

```
// 'form-validate' is the id of the form tag
if ($('form-validate') != undefined) {
    $('form-validate').observe("submit", function() {
       changeText2();
    });
}
```

This would be the quickest solution. Your code should work than.

In almost all templates with forms in Magento on frontend you'll find declarations like:

```
 var dataForm = new VarienForm('my-form-id', true);
```

If you look in js/varien/form.js you'll see:

```
bindElements:function (){
    var elements = Form.getElements(this.form);
```

The html form is hijacked by PrototypeJs class Form which handles the first submit element.

In a more complex example, you'd have to extend the object VarienForm (PrototypeJs way).

```
### Instead of:
// var dataForm = new VarienForm('my-form-id', true);
### you'd have:
var dataForm = new MycompanyForm('my-form-id', true);
```

And inside MycompanyForm class have your magic code that uses Form class.

Thank you